# How to get notification when data change in firebase storage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, notifications

I am working in photo vault app. So i need to detect changes  of firebase database from my app when someone insert new photo or delete photo.I can log in from different device using same user id. I need to reload my collection view in that time. I saw cloud message notification. But i need a notification for data entry. Please help me.

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase now have a new tool called Cloud Functions.

With this you can execute code without a server, listen to Firebase Database and send notifications.

Take a look to the documentation, it's easy:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

Answer (score 0):

Jaime reply about the cloud function suites well if you are inclined to use google offerings. If not, here's how one would approach the problem... Any database is not exposed to client applications directly. Normally there's a web server that writes to the database. So from the web server when you write to database, you can integrate with a unified push notification provider (Amazon SNS, Bluemix Push, etc) to send a notification to the client application on mobile or web.